# Div inside body not filling 100%

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage which has a large amount of unused space at the bottom of the body which I am unable to get rid of.

The body content is not filling 100% of the outer body.

I have tried most things in an attempt to fix this but nothing works - these include setting html, body to `height: 100%` and body to `min-height: 100%`.

I've also made the body content to 100% but the content will not fill the body. Hopefully someone can help!

```
html, body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }

    html {

        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    body {
        background-color: #3BB9C5;
        position: absolute;
        min-height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Without code, we cant see what is wrong. If you use percentages though, I can tell you the parent needs to be set as a height and width. You need to set probably html and body tag as 100% to make it fill.

Comment: Easiest to debug such things is to use the browsers development console and _look_ where the empty space comes from. That gives a clear answer, everything else is just _guessing_ around in the fog.

Comment: I've been doing that but are unable to fix the issue

Comment: Then you should be able to say what element occupies the space and what rule is responsible. Or you have not really looked. Or could it simply be that your content does not consume enough space to use the 100%?

Comment: There is no element filling the space. The div does not fill the body, instead there is just empty body space surrounding it.

Comment: Sorry i answered while you where updating the answer.

Comment: a link to the page would solve for sure.

Comment: I would suggest a [reset CSS](http://cssreset.com/). This minimizes CSS browser differences. And then inspect your webpage with dev tools, to see what's going on.

Comment: @JessCauchi Can you share your HTML also?

Comment: Strange, one of my friends recently had a similar problem in his front page, the bottom seems to keep a blank space, no matter how many rules we applied to the body... This blank space was out of the body element, when _inspecting_ through the layout. He's not too worried about it, since it's not his priority right now, but I have no idea why it happens. If you provide the HTML of that page (remove all unnecessary elements), post in your question.

Comment: @Armfoot Yeah its really strange... although the code below has helped I still have extra space at the bottom again! This is a project for a company so unfortunately I do have to make this a priority :(

Comment: @JessCauchi you can kind of reopen the question my unmarking the accepted answer. Btw, save the entire HTML page and remove all body elements and reopen the page again. If the space is still there, copy that modified HTML into your question. If you use custom Javascript, search for code that modifies the CSS.

Comment: @Armfoot This project is kinda weird.... the reason I cant post the html is due to the fact its been generated by another piece of software. The point of this project is to create an interactive story so we have used a piece of software called Twine to do that. You can then export it into html and add the css/style from there. The problem is, actually accessing the html is nearly impossible as they have formatted it all different to what you would be used to. It's a pain :)

Comment: @JessCauchi My suggestion is to access the HTML as you see it directly in the browser, this means: `File > Save As...` in your browser's menu. Then you can check the generated CSS and HTML. If the HTML is too big, just remove all the inner content of the body from that saved file and reopen that to check if the space is still there. If it is, paste the code in here. And if you don't unmark the accepted check ✔, people may not try to answer to this question anymore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
body, html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    background: #3BB9C5;
}
div{
    height: 100%;
}

<div>sample text</div>
```

This should help

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `position: absolute` from `html`. If possible, remove the whole:

```
html {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me all the time when using chrome browser. Even if I have tried to edit the code on my editor and try to refresh the page it seems to be not working. But if you clear the cache of the browser and reload the page it will magically apply the change on the code.

Funny thing is that I just recently figure out how to disable cache on chrome.
So if just press **F12** and will  open the **Developer tools** on the chrome and go to the **Network Tab** and check the **Disable Cache**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should try to put in your CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

or in your html

```
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;"></body>
```

This could do the trick.